# Wordpress Query ,Get value after a date

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I work on a wordpress theme and i use acf to custom page. I would like to get all the post after the date of today.
I want to display the most recent event to the latest event.
date_debut_evenement is the date of the event. It's a value return from acf

```
 $date = new DateTime("now");
$date = date('Y-m-d');
?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <h4>PDJ à venir</h4>

        <?php
        // args
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'orderby' => 'date_debut_evenement',
            'posts_per_page' => 2,
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key'       => 'date_debut_evenement',
                    'compare'   => '>',
                    'value'     => $date,
                )
            ),

        );
        // query
        $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
        ?>
        <?php if ($the_query->have_posts()): ?>
            <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                <?php
                $type_event= get_field('categorie_evenement');
                $pdj = get_the_title();

                if ($type_event =='pdj') {
                    ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>"> <?php echo $pdj ?></a>
                    <hr>

                    <?php
                }

                ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php wp_reset_query();     // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
        ?>
```

Comment: So what's the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: you need to add the right meta_type too try to add `meta_type=>'DATE'` https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Comment: yes that work but i would like now show old event but that not work. look below i link my code if you know the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your meta_query

From:

```
  'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'date_debut_evenement',
            'compare'   => '>',
            'value'     => $date,
        )
    )
```

To

```
  'meta_query' => array( 
                array('key' => 'date_debut_evenement',
                    'value' => $date,  // <- change
                      'compare' => '>',
                      'type' => 'DATE'
                ),

            )
```

Comment: your Code work for a part . But in the same page i would like to diplay also the event past and most recent to most old, logically i just need to change the code like this . I fact nothing is display while post exist

Comment: You did not mention it before. I told you solution based on that query. I hope you understand. thanks